# How to write a mysql query in cakephp referencing different tables

Tags: cakephp

I have the tables USERS(id, email), MAIL(id, message, receiver, user_id), SERVICES(id, service, user_id)...

A user posts a service, the another user replies to that service through the mail. I want to write a query that will retrieve the email of the user that posted that particular service from USERS and capture it in the receiver field in MAIL when someone replies to the service.

I'm fairly new to cake, and have no idea where to go from here

```
$receiver = $this->User->find('first',array(
             'conditions' => array(
                     'Users.user_id' => 'Services.user_id', 
              )
));

SQL Query

SELECT u.email FROM users AS u, services AS s WHERE s.user_id = u.id LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: first make relationship on model then you would retrieve all information about your user

Comment: please mention your desire query in sql

Comment: Relationships are done, I just need that query

Comment: how is the Email Model related to the Service Model? The recieiver is the id of the user?

Comment: I think you need a `service_id` field in your services table. Otherwise how can you associate an email to a service?

Comment: I do have such a field

Comment: what is? you wrote: MAIL(id, message, receiver, user_id)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have User.php model, create  one action as shown below

```
function getData(){
$options = array(
        //'conditions' => array(‘User.user_id’=>9),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'alias' => 'Service',  
                'table' => ‘services’,
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Service.user_id = User.id',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'alias' => 'Mail',  
                'table' => ‘mail',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Mail.user_id = User.id',
                ),
            )
        ),
        'fields' => array('User.email'),
        'limit'=>10

    );

 $returnData = $this->find('all',$options);
 return $returnData;
}
```

From controller call this method as

```
$data = $this->User->getData();
print_r($data);
```

Hope it will solve your problem!